# gMaps.js maps not rendering. Geocoding multiple addresses and place as markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-geocoder

I have very limited knowledge of javascript and am unable to get gMaps.js to function correctly on my site. Can anyone tell me what I may be doing wrong? I have included the google maps API with sensor set to false. Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  prettyPrint();
  map = new GMaps({
    div: '#map',
    lat: 39.7392,
    lng: 104.9847
  });
  e.preventDefault();
             GMaps.geocode({
      address: $('7310 W 52nd Ave Arvada, CO, 80002').val().trim(),
      callback: function(results, status){
        if(status=='OK'){
          var latlng = results[0].geometry.location;
          map.setCenter(latlng.lat(), latlng.lng());
          map.addMarker({
            lat: latlng.lat(),
            lng: latlng.lng()
          });
        }
      }         GMaps.geocode({
      address: $('2015 E. Colfax Ave Denver, Colorado 80206').val().trim(),
      callback: function(results, status){
        if(status=='OK'){
          var latlng = results[0].geometry.location;
          map.setCenter(latlng.lat(), latlng.lng());
          map.addMarker({
            lat: latlng.lat(),
            lng: latlng.lng()
          });
        }
      }         GMaps.geocode({
      address: $('1090 South Wadsworth Blvd Unit A, Lakewood, CO 80226').val().trim(),
      callback: function(results, status){
        if(status=='OK'){
          var latlng = results[0].geometry.location;
          map.setCenter(latlng.lat(), latlng.lng());
          map.addMarker({
            lat: latlng.lat(),
            lng: latlng.lng()
          });
        }
      }         GMaps.geocode({
      address: $('7349 E 29th Ave, Denver, CO 80238').val().trim(),
      callback: function(results, status){
        if(status=='OK'){
          var latlng = results[0].geometry.location;
          map.setCenter(latlng.lat(), latlng.lng());
          map.addMarker({
            lat: latlng.lat(),
            lng: latlng.lng()
          });
        }
      }
  });
```

Comment: I would suggest using Google Chrome and opening the "developer tools" and then open your page.  This should give you a clue about what is happening by looking at the console.  Questions on StackOverflow should include 1) What you expected, 2) What you got and 3) relevant code.  "Function correctly" is a very vague goal.

Answer (score 0):

Hi and sorry for the late answer! It seems like you're trying to use jQuery in a wrong way:

```
$('7310 W 52nd Ave Arvada, CO, 80002').val().trim()
```

should either be a string only:

```
'7310 W 52nd Ave Arvada, CO, 80002'
```

...or reference an input field or text area in your HTML:

```
$('#id_of_html_element').val().trim()
```

where an input field could look like this:

```
<input id="id_of_html_element" />
```

See the jQuery selectors reference for further information: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors.